# Setting up a DNS server for a 3rd level domain

Tags: domain-name-system

If I would like a client to use HIS DNS for a 3rd level domain name (ie test.domain.com), how would I be able to do that?

So I have domain servers ns1.domain.com + ns2.domain.com for domain.com  but now I want ns1.rabbit.com and ns2.rabbit.com for test.domain.com.

How can this be done? I know it's possible because I saw it at some providers.

Then, as a second part (and related) part; how to set up a WHOIS for that test.domain.com? So that, if you query my server for the information about test.domain.com, it'll be different than the info on domain.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Whois: not at all. Subdomain are not managed by public infrastructure, so you do not have to provide them. If you do (are sort of a registry), get a whois server.
- Just enter delegations for the relevant *zone* (the term domain does actually not exist in this context in DNS - RTFM) to the dns servers of your client. He is then responsible for making his DNS servers authoritative for this zone.

Comment: That sounds logical. Thanks. So you mean to put, in the zone record test.domain.com. 86400 IN NS ns1.rabbit.com etc? That should do it right? Thanks again.